# Is there a way to filter JSON data with Python

Tags: python, json, numpy, dictionary, prtg

I'm using PRTG HTTP API to pull sensors information, my goal is to filter up the sensors that have this value

```
<status>Down</status>
```

So far I've read a lot of references in Stack and Googling but I have not been able to apply none of this solutions, so pasting all the codes I've tried would be futile however the one that makes more sense to me is this one

The structure of the JSON is like this

```
{
  "prtg-version": "19.1.49.1966",
  "treesize": 17701,
  "status%3Ddown": [
    {
      "group": "SOME GROUP",
      "device": "SOME SWITCH",
      "sensor": "Uptime",
      "status": "Down",
      "status_raw": 5
    },
    {
      "group": "SOME GROUP",
      "device": "SOME SWITCH",
      "sensor": "System Health Memory",
      "status": "Up",
      "status_raw": 3
    },
  ]
}
```

Now here's the code

```
import json
import requests
url = "https://prtg.c3ntro.com/api/table.jsoncontent=status=down&username=usr&passhash=hash&count=100"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

d = data
result_dict = [d for d in data['status%3Ddown'] if d['status'] == 'Down']
print(result_dict)


#Code has been fixed and now it works
```

## This prints out only Down status sensors now

Comment: What do you expect `data["prtg-version", "treesize", "status%3Ddown"]` to do?

Comment: Sorry I pasted wrong code I guess, I was actually using ata["device", "status", "status%3Ddown"] dictionary but I got it working with "davedwards" answer thanks everyone code is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list comprehension should work:

```
[d for d in data['status%3Ddown'] if d['status'] == 'Down']
```

returns all entries in `"status%3Ddown"` list that contain `"status": "Down"`:

```
[{'device': 'SOME SWITCH',
  'group': 'SOME GROUP',
  'sensor': 'Uptime',
  'status': 'Down',
  'status_raw': 5}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dave it works now, code has been fixed in the question just to show how it got fixed (:

Answer (score 0):

```
d = data["prtg-version", "treesize", "status%3Ddown"]
```

That line of code is trying to access an element with the literal three-part key `"prtg-version", "treesize", "status%3Ddown"`, which of course doesn't exist.

It looks like you just want this:

```
d = data["status%3Ddown"]
```